# Using count, sum, and group by in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that shows the number of orders and the number of items each customer has bought in those orders

```
SELECT customers.customer_id, COUNT(orders.order_id),  
SUM(order_details.order_qty)
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders 
ON orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_details 
ON order_details.order_id=orders.order_id
GROUP BY customers.customer_id;
```

I have three tables to join, as you can see in what I've written so far...the problem is that my query results are wrong

[image]

customer_id: 1 should have 3 orders and the quantity of items n those orders should be 5

Here is another image below to show what the other tables contain:
[image]

I'm using Oracle Database version 12.2.0.1.0

Order_details:
[image]

orders:
[image]

customers:
[image]

Comment: Without the data that generated those results, we can't help you.

Comment: i've added samples of the data

Comment: A sample of the data that supports your assertion `1 should have 3 orders and the quantity of items n those orders should be 5` would have been helpful. A random smattering of orders and items that are unrelated to each other and unrelated to the results you're disputing, is Pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that my query results are wrong

At a guess your orders have more than one details record. So just joining them like this will generate a Product based on the number of Details records..

What you can do is use an inline view to aggregate the `qty` per Order ID;

```
SELECT customers.customer_id
       , COUNT(orders.order_id)
       , SUM(order_details.tot_qty)
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders 
ON orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select order_id, SUM(order_qty) as tot_qty 
                 from order_details 
                 group by order_id) order_details
ON order_details.order_id=orders.order_id
GROUP BY customers.customer_id;
```

Comment: That would fix COUNT(order_id) but wouldn't change the result of SUM(qty). The op "claims" they get a result of 7 for SUM(qty), where they "assert" that they should get 5. Unfortunately the sample data they included bears no relation to their assertion, so it's hard to say what they talking about :(